# Excel macro Interior.color

Tags: vba, excel

I'm new to Excel macros and I am having some trouble getting this macro I wrote to work. When I try to run this script I get a "Runtime Error '13' Type mismatch" error. What I am trying to do is have excel check is a cell is black, then if it is, have Excel add the corresponding number in 'myBit' to 'ans' and at the end of the row, set column 'J' to 'ans' and then repeated for the next column. Sorry if you found this confusing but I did my best at trying to explain what I am trying to do.

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Dim myRow
Dim myBit
Dim ans As Integer
Dim c As Integer
Dim r As Integer
myRow = Array("B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I")
myBit = Array(128, 64, 32, 16, 8, 4, 2, 1)
c = 0
r = 3
For r = 3 To 11
    ans = 0
    For c = 0 To 8
        If Cells(myRow(c) + r).Interior.Color = RGB(0, 0, 0) Then ans = ans + myBit(c)
    Cells("J" + r).Value = ans
    Next c
Next r
End Sub
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The syntax for `Cells` is `Cells(Row,Column)`. Please see this

[Worksheet.Cells Property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/worksheet-cells-property-excel)

You need `Range` instead of that. Also few things are not required. Is this what you are trying (**Not tested thoroughly**)?

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Dim ans As Integer, c As Integer, r As Integer
    Dim myRow, myBit

    myRow = Array("B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I")
    myBit = Array(128, 64, 32, 16, 8, 4, 2, 1)

    For r = 3 To 11
        ans = 0
        For c = 0 To 8
            If Range(myRow(c) & r).Interior.Color = RGB(0, 0, 0) Then _
            ans = ans + Val(myBit(c))

            Range("J" & r).Value = ans
        Next c
    Next r
End Sub
```

Comment: Thankyou! I just corrected the code for the 'For ' loop as you put 8 instead of 7, but this works wonderfully now

Comment: I put `8` because you have `8` in the original question :)